# Hadoop 0.23.9 How to Start datanodes

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

It seems like I can't get hadoop to start properly.  I'm using hadoop 0.23.9:

```
[msknapp@localhost sbin]$ hadoop namenode -format
...
[msknapp@localhost sbin]$ ./start-dfs.sh 
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/cloud/hadoop-0.23.9/logs/hadoop-msknapp-namenode-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/cloud/hadoop-0.23.9/logs/hadoop-msknapp-datanode-localhost.localdomain.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/cloud/hadoop-0.23.9/logs/hadoop-msknapp-secondarynamenode-localhost.localdomain.out
[msknapp@localhost sbin]$ ./start-yarn.sh 
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/cloud/hadoop-0.23.9/logs/yarn-msknapp-resourcemanager-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/cloud/hadoop-0.23.9/logs/yarn-msknapp-nodemanager-localhost.localdomain.out
[msknapp@localhost sbin]$ cd /var/local/stock/data
[msknapp@localhost data]$ hadoop fs -ls /
[msknapp@localhost data]$ hadoop fs -mkdir /stock
[msknapp@localhost data]$ ls
companies.csv  raw  slf_series.txt
[msknapp@localhost data]$ hadoop fs -put companies.csv /stock/companies.csv 
13/12/08 11:10:40 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
java.io.IOException: File /stock/companies.csv._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:414)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1565)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1094)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:195)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1006)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:458)
put: File /stock/companies.csv._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
13/12/08 11:10:40 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close file /stock/companies.csv._COPYING_
java.io.IOException: File /stock/companies.csv._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:414)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1565)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1094)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:195)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1006)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:458)
```

Here is my core-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
</property>
```

and my hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
</property>
```

and mapred-site.xml:

```
    <property>
            <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
            <value>localhost:8021</value>
    </property>
```

I looked through all the documentation I have, I cannot figure out how to start hadoop correctly.  I can't find any documentation online about hadoop-0.23.9.  My Hadoop book is written for 0.22.  The online documentation is for 2.1.1, which coincidentally I could not get to work.

Can somebody please tell me how to get my hadoop started correctly?

Comment: you may want to check the datanode log file for detailed error information

Answer (score 2):

Specify a port for `fs.default.name`

like:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
</property>
```

After that, create a tmp directory for hdfs:

```
sudo mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp
sudo chown you /app/hadoop/tmp
```

and add to core-site.xml:

```
<property>
   <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
   <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
   <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
```

Make sure to restart your cluster.

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/stop-all.sh
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-all.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting all the data with hadoop stopped:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop datanode -format
```

or manually delete the contents of

> /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data/

and then start hadoop again:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-all.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

The key problem in your configuration is as below:

```
java.io.IOException: File /stock/companies.csv._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Make sure your HDFS specific configuration has at least minimum of as below:

hdfs-site.xml:
As shows in the xml you must have /tmp/hdfs23/namenode and /tmp/hdfs23/datanode folder already existed. You can configure any other folder for hdfs root and then namenode and datanode folder insider it.

```
<configuration>
        <property>
           <name>dfs.replication</name>
           <value>1</value>
        </property>
        <property>
           <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
           <value>file:///tmp/hdfs23/namenode</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>fs.checkpoint.dir</name>
            <value>file:///tmp/hdfs23/secnamenode</value>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>fs.checkpoint.edits.dir</name>
             <value>file:///tmp/hdfs23/secnamenode</value>
        </property>
        <property>
           <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
           <value>file:///tmp/hdfs23/datanode</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
        <property>
            <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
            <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
        </property>
     <property>
         <name>fs.default.name</name>
         <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>hadoop.http.staticuser.user</name>
        <value>hdfs</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

Then you need to format your namenode as you already did:

```
$ hadoop namenode -format
```

After that you can start HDFS as below:

```
[Hadoop023_ROOT]/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

Comment: If it still doesn't solve the problem, try remove all files and folders in "real" `namenode` folder and `datanode` folder.  For example, remove all things in `file:///tmp/hdfs23/namenode` before format `namenode`.